# How to add launcher icon for python script?

Tags: python, launcher, icons, window-manager, .desktop

I am trying to add a launcher icon for a custom Python script showing a Tkinter window (script location: `/home/hakon/my-tkapp.py`):

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk(className='MyTkApp')
label = tk.Label(root, text="Hello World")
label.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

The script is executable. I am using `pyenv`, so if I run the following from `gnome-terminal`:

```
$ which python3
/home/hakon/.pyenv/shims/python3
```

I created a desktop file (file location: `~/.local/share/applications/my-tk-app.desktop`):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Name=My Tk Application
Exec=/home/hakon/my-tkapp.py
Icon=/home/hakon/icons/my-tk-app-icon.png
StartupWMClass=MyTkApp
```

For the icon, I just (for the purpose of testing) copied one of the standard icons:

```
cp /usr/share/icons/hicolor/48/apps/apport.png /home/hakon/icons/my-tk-app-icon.png
```

Running the `desktop-file-validate` command on the desktop file gives no output, so the desktop file should be OK.

However, when I run the python script from the terminal:

```
~/my-tkapp.py
```

I still get the generic question mark icon in the launcher.

What am I overlooking here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Due to the fact that your question is nicely documented, we can find the problem :)

- In your application, you set:

  ```py
  root = tk.Tk(className='MyTkApp')
  ```
- Now if you open a terminal, type:

  ```
  $ xprop WM_CLASS
  ```

  and subsequently click on the window of your application, it shows:

  ```
  WM_CLASS(STRING) = "myTkApp", "Mytkapp"
  ```

This is ***just*** not the same as the window class you set; the capitals are different. The only conclusion is that for some reason, the window class (capital-format) you set is not accepted by the window manager.

When I changed your launcher to match `myTkApp`:

```
StartupWMClass=myTkApp
```

it works fine (for convenience reason, I set the firefox icon, since I don't have your icon):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Name=My Tk Application
Exec=/home/jacob/Bureaublad/testapp.py
Icon=firefox
StartupWMClass=myTkApp
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Hi Jacob, now I got another problem that I think is related to `tkinter`, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44795622/2173773) question

Comment: I wanted to do this too! I made an icon and followed your and Hakon's instructions.Worked first time! Fantastic! Thank you both!

Comment: Didn't work for me.